# Eclipse only shows me the prototype of the shared library function, not the definition

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt, content-assist

When I hover on a function, by using `Ctrl+click`, Eclipse sends me by default to the prototype of the function in the header file.

I'd like to see the definition of this function but I see no link when hovering or using the right click?

Is that something in the config I need to set?

It's a shared library by the way (I can compile my program without problem)

Comment: The library doesn't contain the definition - you need its source code.

Comment: I can get the source from which the shared library was compiled I guess. But then is there a way that for a function, Eclipse shows me the corresponding source code? EDIT: Okay I've found it. I need to go into 'properties'>'C/C++ general'>'Preprocessor include'>'GNU C++' and in 'CDT User settings Entries' past the path to the library source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found it. After having paste in one of my project folders  the source code from which the shared library was compiled, I need to go into 'properties'>'C/C++ general'>'Preprocessor include'>'GNU C++' and in 'CDT User settings Entries' paste the path to the library source folder.

`Ctrl+click` then shows me directly the definition of the function. I can do `Ctrl+click` again (but on the `.cpp` file) to get the prototype (as before).

Other solution: Pressing `F3`, and `F3` again.